# Java/Kotlin Encrypt AES key with private and public key

Tags: java, encryption, kotlin, aes, rsa

so I lately saw a video from computerphile where they said that when using encryption you should be using AES keys and encrypt this key with public and private key. This means: I have a public key from someone else, and my own private key.

The reason behind encrypting it with your own private key is, that this verifies that the message has to be comming from me, because no one else has my private key, so encryption with my public key can only work on messages comming from me.

Problem is that after my first encryption, the byte array outcomming becomes too long and I cant encrypt it another time. Is there a way around this?

This is my code:

```
val aKey = generateAESKey()

val kG = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
kG.initialize(2048)
val own = kG.genKeyPair()
val strange = kG.genKeyPair()

String(aKey.encoded).encryptRSA(strange.public).encryptRSA(own.public)

fun generateAESKey(): Key {
val generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
generator.init(128)
return generator.generateKey()

fun String.encryptRSA(key: Key): String {
    val encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray(charset("UTF-
    8")))
    return String(cipherText)
}

fun String.decryptRSA(key: Key): String {
    val bytes = this.toByteArray()
    val decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
    return String(decryptCipher.doFinal(bytes), charset("UTF-8"))
}
```

This for example gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at de.intektor.kentai_http_common.util.EncryptionKt.encryptRSA(encryption.kt:30)
at de.intektor.test.TestKt.main(Test.kt:19)
```

Of course this is just a testcase.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html

Comment: We do not 'encrypt' with private keys.  Instead, we 'digitally sign' with private keys.

Comment: And it's standard, conventional, and almost always better to sign the whole message (not just the key), preferably after encrypting, unless (you are certain) your encryption is not malleable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Not with asymmetric crypto, it is not. Somebody could strip the signature and replace it. For asymmetric you'd use sign-then-encrypt. For AES you could still use GCM mode or encrypt-then-mac of course.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: why is that bad? Bob shouldn't trust _any_ signature from Mallory, ever. And with StE if signing is deterministic (sometimes) and encryption malleable (sometimes) and known-plaintext possible (more often than designers/admins expect) attacker can replace the signature so you're no better off. GCM is one good certain way of being unmalleable. EtS does make it somewhat more difficult to forward the signed data to a third party, including an arbiter, but whether that's a problem depends on applications not mentioned in the Q.

Comment: "Bob shouldn't trust any signature from Mallory, ever." No, this is not true, Mallory could be in the same PKI; think for instance about PGP signatures or code signing. Often just the CA is trusted. I agree that care should be taken to implement StE. And if the key of Bob can be explicitly trusted, then EtS *could* work, as long as you're OK with storing the ciphertext in addition to the plaintext. But in general StE is used for asymmetric and in that case authenticated ciphers such as GCM are an extremely good idea.