# What is Kotlin equivalent of funtion openssl_private_decrypt?

Tags: php, kotlin, openssl

I have used `openssl_public_encrypt` function in a PHP-based server to encrypt a message with a public key. The crypted message is sent to a Kotlin-based server. If it were in PHP, the decryption would be done by using `openssl_private_decrypt`. How can I decrypt the message in Kotlin?

Comment: Perhaps this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205964/java-kotlin-encrypt-aes-key-with-private-and-public-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the equivalent code in Kotlin:

```
private fun decrypt(cryptedData: ByteArray): String {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")  //"PKCS1Padding" is the default padding
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
    val res = cipher.doFinal(cryptedData).toHexString()
    val decrypted = hexToAscii(res)
    return decrypted
}
```